# magento 1.9.1.0 elevateZoom not loaded/working first time on custom theme

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I'm using 1.9.1.0 and custom theme(shopper theme)

i have copied media.phtml and app.js etc(from rwd) for zoom purpose

Zoom is not loaded for first time but when i clicked on thumbnail(more views) elevateZoom loaded properly also i found that  second image of the peoduct loaded first

It is clear that though i using custom theme  i've to do two things manually
1)In product details page first image(base image) will be loaded first
2)And elevateZoom also loaded

But i failed to find out the page where i change the code by jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try have a look on this file: **(/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js)** and look for image.elevateZoom();and check if it is commented, if so, delete the comments and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who already has noConflict setup and is still running in to problems I finally found this solution on [a ticket raised on Github](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom/issues/74)

```
// First call elevateZoom

$j(document).ready(function() {     
  $j('.product-image-thumbs').attr('id', 'zoomGallery');

  //initiate the plugin and pass the id of the div containing gallery images 

  $j("#image-main").elevateZoom({gallery:'zoomGallery', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active', imageCrossfade: true, loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'}); 

 //pass the images to Fancybox 

 $j("#image-main").bind("click", function(e) { 
    var ez = $j('#image-main').data('elevateZoom');    
    $j.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList()); 
    return false; 
 }); 

// after click you need to remove the current zoom 

$j(".product-image-thumbs li img").click(function(){
    $j("#image-main").attr("src", $j(this).attr("data-main-image-src"));
    $j('.zoomContainer').remove();
    $j('#image-main').removeData('elevateZoom');

// and then call it again

$j('#image-main').elevateZoom({
    gallery: 'more-vies',
    lensSize: 200,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    galleryActiveClass: 'active',
    imageCrossfade: true,
    scrollZoom : true,
    responsive: true
  });
});
});
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*